# How to extend/overwrite symfony2 form_row function

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I would like to use `form_row(form.myfield)` in my twig template to render the whole row (label, error, widget) of a form field.

But I would like to overwrite the `form_widget()` function to give out some help message.

My question now is: How to extend/overwrite the `form_row()` function to add an attribute with my help message, that is transfered to the `form_widget()` function?

What i would like to use:

```
{ form_row(form.firstname, { 'attr': {'helpmsg': 'I am your help buddy'} }
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-help-messages) or do you want something different ?

Comment: yes exactly. make an answer and i'll accept it. thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you were looking for [this page of the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-help-messages).